# Program in C executed and the terminal shows: Finished (killed)

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I was running a program in C from the terminal in Linux and I get the message "Finished (killed)". From the output obtained I see that the execution is more or less always killed at the same point. I am also working with a huge amount of data and I am executing the program locally in my computer.

Writing in the console ulimit -a I get the following information:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 29117
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 29117
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

But I see in there normal values.

I do not know what to do in order to get the whole execution completed. I've optimized the code and freed memory but I get the same problem "(killed)".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define T 100
#define dt 1.e-4
#define itmax (T/dt)

#define a 0.27

#define K1 0.15
#define K2 1.e2
#define pp 1.e3
#define s 2

#define TWOPI (6.2831853071795864769252867665590057683943387987502)
#define IM1 2147483563
#define IM2 2147483399
#define AM (1.0/IM1)
#define IMM1 (IM1-1)
#define IA1 40014
#define IA2 40692
#define IQ1 53668
#define IQ2 52774
#define IR1 12211
#define IR2 3791
#define NTAB 32
#define NDIV (1+IMM1/NTAB)
#define EPS 1.2e-7
#define RNMX (1.0-EPS)

double ran2(double *idum){
  int j;
  long k;
  static long idum2=123456789;
  static long iy=0;
  static long iv[NTAB];
  float temp;

  if (*idum <= 0) {
    if (-(*idum) < 1) *idum=1;
    else *idum = -(*idum);
    idum2=(*idum);
    for (j=NTAB+7;j>=0;j--) {
      k=(*idum)/IQ1;
      *idum=IA1*(*idum-k*IQ1)-k*IR1;
      if (*idum < 0) *idum += IM1;
      if (j < NTAB) iv[j] = *idum;
    }
    iy=iv[0];
  }
  k=(*idum)/IQ1;
  *idum=IA1*(*idum-k*IQ1)-k*IR1;
  if (*idum < 0) *idum += IM1;
  k=idum2/IQ2;
  idum2=IA2*(idum2-k*IQ2)-k*IR2;
  if (idum2 < 0) idum2 += IM2;
  j=iy/NDIV;
  iy=iv[j]-idum2;
  iv[j] = *idum;
  if (iy < 1) iy += IMM1;
  if ((temp=AM*iy) > RNMX) return RNMX;
  else return temp;
}

double RANDN(double seed){
  return sqrt(-2.0*log(ran2(&seed)))*cos(TWOPI*ran2(&seed));
}

double rnd(){
  return (double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
}

int main(){
  int j, rows, d;
  d=0;
  double *t;
  t=(double *) malloc((itmax)*sizeof(double)); 

  double **x, **y;
  x=(double **)malloc(2*sizeof(double*));
  y=(double **)malloc(2*sizeof(double*));

  for(rows=0; rows<2; rows++){
    x[rows]=(double*)malloc(itmax*sizeof(double));
    y[rows]=(double*)malloc(itmax*sizeof(double));
  }

  double p, L, C, bC, Qx, Qy;
  double bx, by Qbx, Qby, KK, KKK, dt2;

  srand(time(NULL));

  t[0]=0;
  for(rows=0; rows<2; rows++){
    x[rows][0]=10+rows*i;
    y[rows][0]=1300;
  } 

  L=s*0.0001;

  KK=K1*K1;
  KKK=K2*K2;
  dt2=0.5*dt;
  C=KK*KKK;
  bC=a*C;
  for(j=0; j<=itmax; j++){
    p=pp-x[0][j]+x[1][j];

    Qx=a+bC/(KK+C)-a*x[0][j]*y[0][j];
    Qy=y[1][j]-y[0][j];

    bx=x[0][j]+dt*Qx+L*RANDN(rnd()+2);
    by=y[0][j]+dt*Qy+L*RANDN(rnd()+2);

    Qbx=a+bC/(KK+C)-a*bx*by-a*bx;
    Qby=y[0][j]-y[1][j];;

    x[0][j+1]=(bx+x[0][j])/2+(Qbx+Qx)*2;
    y[0][j+1]=(by+y[0][j])/2+(Qby+Qy)*2;

    Qx=a+bC/KK-a*x[1][j]*y[1][j];
    Qy=y[1][j];

    bx=x[1][j]+dt*Qx;
    by=y[1][j]+dt*Qy;

    Qbx=a+C/(KK+C)-a*bx*by-a*bx;
    Qby=by*(y[1][j]-y[0][j]);

    x[1][j+1]=(bx+x[1][j])/2+(Qbx+Qx)*dt2+L*RANDN(rnd()+2);
    y[1][j+1]=(by+y[1][j])/2+(Qby+Qy)*dt2+L*RANDN(rnd()+2);

    if(j==d){
      d+=T;
      printf("%G %G %G %G %G\n",t[j],x[0][j],x[1][j],y[0][j],y[1][j]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a_ specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary _to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly lack a *swap* partition, or you have some other utility monitoring the amount of available *free memory*, and therefore your program is *killed* because it **consumes too much memory**, up to the point that there is no free *ram* left.

You can use **htop** or **conky** to have a clear view of the issue.

---

If instead you had a *swap* partition then your system would attempt to *swap* the memory from/to the disk, and this would most likely *freeze* it. This is a much worse scenario, because in most cases the only action that you can take to get the system back working is to *reboot* it: in my experience, when the system freezes then it no longer responds to any keyboard input.

---

On my system it takes *2m26s* for your executable to fill over *50%* of the available *8GB* of *RAM*, not counting the additional *32%* that is occupied by the other running programs.

---

You might want to use a **memory leak profiling tool** (e.g. **valgrind**) to check for potential leaks, or simply inspect the source code manually. If you can't reduce its memory footprint, then your only option is to look for a much more powerful machine with a larger pool of *RAM*.

Answer (score 2):

Compile and link with debugging information using `-g`, then run the program under control of a debugger such as `gdb` and watch where it stops.  You should see which line of source code causes the problem that gets your program killed by the system.

```
$ gcc -O2 -g -o my_program my_program.c
$ gdb my_program
gdb> run
```

If your program needs command line arguments, type them on the `run` command

```
gdb> run arg1 arg2
```

Comment: I've written what you have recommended, adding `-lm` in the first line, and I've obtained **Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.** What should I do to avoid the problem?

Comment: @S.Proa Try typing `bt` to run a backtrace after the crash occurs, to see the chain of calls that led to it. This is basic debugging; please research it.

Comment: @underscore_d This command does not work... I get the message "No stack.".

Comment: Can you confirm exactly the `gcc` and `gdb` command lines that you used? But more to the point - why haven't you shown us any code? What program are you compiling/running? What does it do? What are we meant to do, guess? For all we know, your program sends itself `SIGKILL` or causes another process to do so.

Comment: I already post the code. I just did not know how to put so many lines of code directly...
With this program I want to get a text file with the corresponding values (in the `printf`) and then plot all the data with gnuplot.
Commands that I used: 
`$ gcc -O2 -g -o my_program my_program.c -lm`
`$ gdb my_program`
`gdb> run`
`gdb> bt` or `gdb> backtrace` and neither of the backtrace commands work.